# How to find the sum of a sequence, e.g. $(2n - 1)^3$

Tags: summation

I need to find the sum of this series:

$1^3$, $-2^3$, $3^3$, $-4^3$, ... ,$2n^3$

so I've split that up into:

$\sum_{r = 1}^n (2r-1)^3 - \sum_{r = 1}^n (2r)^3$

So all I need is how to find: $\sum_{r = 1}^n (2r-1)^3$

Comment: $(2r-1)^3=8r^3-12r^2+6r-1$.

Comment: It seems, from the first terms, that the general term of the sequence is $$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}n^3$$ Is this right?

Comment: Yeah that is the general term

Comment: $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}(2r-1)^3 - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}(2r)^3 = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}8r^3 - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}12r^2+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}6r - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}1 - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}8r^3 = -12\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^2 + 6\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r - \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}1 = -2n(n+1)(2n+1)+3n(n+1)-n = -4n^3-3n^2$

Comment: What are you looking for
$$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}k^3\quad\text{or}\quad\sum_{k=1}^n[(2k-1)^3-(2k)^3]}\;\;\;{\Huge \color{red}{?}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: notice $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}(2r-1)^3$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left((2r)^2-(1)^3-3(2r)(1)(2r-1)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(8r^3-12r^2+6r-1\right)$$
$$=8\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^3-12\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2+6\sum_{r=1}^{n}r-\sum_{r=1}^{n}1$$
$$=8\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-12\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)+6\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-n$$
You can solve further by simplifying

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The required(original one i.e. $1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 - ... - (2n)^3$) sum is $\sum_{r = 1}^{2n} r^3 - 16\sum_{r = 1}^n r^3.$ Use the formula to calculate the sum of $1^{st} n$  cubes.

Comment: You should be clear you are talking about the initial sum, not the sum derived later.